# How to Restructure dataframe from an excel sheet in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use this code to send my messages via whatsApp with contact data extracted from an excel sheet:
It works just fine if I manually remove blank lines from the source excel sheet. But if I try to remove the unwanted rows from the dataframe with a script, it throws errors.

**step 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
data = pd.read_excel("SGA Cristina.xlsx",  header=3, usecols=[0,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
print(data)
```

**step 2**
I replaced reformatted with:

```
#convert integer to string
dataNew = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= 
['Cliente','Placas','Numero','Vencimento','Boleto','Valor'])
dataNew['Numero'] = data['Numero'].astype(str) 
#add country code
dataNew['Numero'] = dataNew['Numero'].str.replace(r"\(", "55",regex=True)
#remove parentases 
dataNew['Numero'] = dataNew['Numero'].str.replace(r"\)", "",regex=True)
#remove dashs from  telephone number
dataNew['Numero'] = dataNew['Numero'].str.replace("-","",regex=True)


display(dataNew)
```

**Step 3**

Open whatsApp app and send messages:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

while len(navegador.find_elements_by_id("side")) < 1:
time.sleep(1)

# connected whatsapp web
for i, mensagem in enumerate(dataNew['Vencimento']):
pessoa = dataNew.loc[i, "Cliente"]
numero = dataNew.loc[i, "Numero"]
valor = dataNew.loc[i, "Valor"]
texto = urllib.parse.quote(f"Oi {pessoa}! {numero}, sua fatura no valor de {valor}, vence 
hoje")
link = f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={numero}&text={texto}"
navegador.get(link)
while len(navegador.find_elements_by_id("side")) < 1:
    time.sleep(1)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
```

So far this works just fine.

My problem is that if I try to remove unwanted or blank rows with the code below, I end up getting an error.

Code inserted before **step 2** to remove blank or incomplete rows with empty or unwanted data and restructure dataframe:

```
nan_value = float("NaN")

data.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
data.dropna(subset = ["Cliente"],inplace=True)
data.dropna(subset = ["Placas"],inplace=True)
display(data)
```

Although this does display the dataframe correctly, when I run **step 3** it throws the error.

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method,
tolerance)
3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3081             except KeyError as err:

```
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-19f3fa7fdc7a> in <module>
 40 # connected whatsapp web
 41 for i, mensagem in enumerate(dataNew['Vencimento']):
 ---> 42     pessoa = dataNew.loc[i, "Cliente"]
 43     numero = dataNew.loc[i, "Numero"]
 44     valor = dataNew.loc[i, "Valor"]

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
 887                     # AttributeError for IntervalTree get_value
 888                     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
 --> 889             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  890         else:
 891             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
  1058     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):
  1059         with suppress(IndexingError):
 -> 1060             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  1061 
  1062         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
 805                 # We don't need to check for tuples here because those are
 806                 #  caught by the _is_nested_tuple_indexer check above.
--> 807                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
 808 
 809                 # We should never have a scalar section here, because

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
 1122         # fall thru to straight lookup
 1123         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1124         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
 1125 
  1126     def _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj: slice, axis: int):

3083 
3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: This is only a wild guess, but have you tried resetting the index after removing the lines with empty cells (`data = data.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: Ok. Is this the correct syntax? after line `data.dropna(subset = ["Placas"],inplace=True)` I placed `data.reset_index(drop=True)` but I still get the same error!

Comment: I need help please

Comment: This worked for me. `dataNew.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` could someone elaborate as to why?

Comment: Without resetting the index, your iteration in step 3 tried to access indices of rows which have been removed. Hence, you received a KeyError.